# Не получается mul

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Почему у меня не компилируется умножение?

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
 Main   PROTO 
 .data 
a dd 4 
b dd 5  
 .code 

 start: 
 invoke Main 
 invoke ExitProcess,0 
 Main proc 
 mov cx,a
 mov ax,b
mul ax    
 Main endp 

 end start
```

> ```
> Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997. All rights reserved.
>
>  Assembling: number.asm
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> UNICODE Build
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> number.asm(23) : error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
> number.asm(24) : error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
> Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "number.obj"
> Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
> ```

Comment: http://www.kolasc.net.ru/cdo/programmes/assembler/mul.html   mul предполагает второй операнд умножения в ax и использовать ax как первый операнд, указанный в команде не может. используйте другой регистр

Comment: @Mike, очень даже может. [скриншот](http://i.imgur.com/Ug468ux.png)

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy, какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @insolor Но в любом случае он тогда умножит ax сам на себя, он же не догадается, что второй операнд в cx

Comment: @Mike, согласен.

Comment: @insolor тему обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче всё просто, нужно было не в cx пихать число, а в eax. Профит :)

```
.486 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap :none 
__UNICODE__ equ 1 
include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 

Main PROTO
.data 
    a dd 4 
    b dd 5
    
.code
start: 
    invoke Main 
    invoke ExitProcess,0 

Main proc 
    mov eax,a
    mov ebx,b
    mul ebx    
Main endp 

end start
```

Comment: Небольшая придирка: по соглашению [stdcall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) процедура не должна, в частности, модифицировать регистры ebx, edi, esi (если сильно нужно - то сохранять их значение на входе, и восстанавливать при выходе из процедуры). Лучше использовать регистры eax, ecx, edx.

Answer (score 4):

Вот 23, 24 строки:

```
mov cx,a
mov ax,b
```

Ошибка переводится так: "Операнды инструкции должны быть одного размера".

Здесь проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь положить содержимое переменных `a` и `b` (которые у вас объявлены как 32-битные с помощью `dd`) в регистры `ax`, `cx` (16-битные). Нужно или менять размер переменных, или брать 32-битные регистры. Т.к. программа в целом 32-битная, то и регистры и переменные эффективнее использовать 32-битные.

Другая ошибка: `mul ax` умножает `ax` само на себя, а вам нужно `cx` умножить на `ax`. Для этого нужна команда `mul cx`.

Comment: не, оно жаловалось на то что я переменную типа DD хотел вставить в регистр меньшего размера и всё )

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy, в коде, приведенном в вопросе, две проблемы, в ответе я указал их обе. Вторую вы в своем коде исправили, но в своем ответе не акцентировали на нее внимание.

Comment: ну да, есть такое :D

Comment: а как вот мне потом пару edx:eax переместить(mov) в переменную "a"?

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy, пару 32-битных значений в одну 32-битную переменную - никак. Если edx не равен 0, то либо считать что у вас арифметическое переполнение, и обрабатывать это как ошибку, либо сохранять результат по частям в 64-битную переменную.

Comment: ну я короче сделал просто "mov a,eax" и всё, мне кажется этого будет достаточно )

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy, при умножении небольших чисел - достаточно. А вообще, никто не гарантирует, например, что пользователь не введет довольно большие числа, и случится переполнение.